# sql oracle how to count value increases in column

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help counting the number of times a column's value increased and decreased for a certain ID.

I have data that looks like this

```
ID  Month   Value1  
1   1   500  
1   2   500  
1   3   500  
1   4   1000  
2   1   1000  
2   2   500  
2   3   500  
2   4   1000  
3   1   6000  
3   2   6000  
3   3   5000  
3   4   5000
```

And I want this

```
ID  Increases   Decreases  
1   1   0  
2   1   1  
3   0   1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can there be any month gaps, or duplicate months for an id?

Comment: This depends much on the database engine you are using. Please tag your question with the database engine.

Comment: if you are on sql-server take a look at lag function

Comment: What database are you using and what have you already tried?

Comment: @jarlh yes there can be month gaps (I'm working with missing data) but no duplicate IDs per month

Comment: @trincot I am connecting to oracle

Comment: If there can be gaps, can't you adjust the sample data and expected result to include such gap.

Comment: @RichBenner I am connecting to Oracle, and I have not tried anything yet, I have been pondering and researching. I know I can't simply look for distinct values and group by ID

Comment: @jarlh I am only missing 2 months worth of data, I think I will make the assumption that Value1 does not change from the previous non-missing month

Comment: @apomene I have used a lag function in R before. If this is not available in sql oracle perhaps there's a way I can make a duplicate lagged column within each ID group and do calculations from there

Comment: Did any of the answers meet your needs? If so, could you mark the answer of your choice as accepted or else leave a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated column using the `lead` function which gets the values from the next row. Then aggregate based on the calculated column.

```
select id,
count(case when inc_or_dec = 'increase' then 1 end) increases,
count(case when inc_or_dec = 'decrease' then 1 end) decreases
from (
select id,
case 
when coalesce(lead(value1) over(partition by id order by mth),value1) > value1 then 'increase'
when coalesce(lead(value1) over(partition by id order by mth),value1) < value1 then 'decrease'
when coalesce(lead(value1) over(partition by id order by mth),value1) = value1 then 'no change'
end inc_or_dec
from tablename) t
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Only for fun ;) with [sign](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions164.htm#SQLRF06106) function:

```
  SELECT id, SUM (SIGN (di + 1)) incCount, SUM (SIGN (di - 1)*-1) decCount
    FROM (SELECT id, SIGN (LEAD (value1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, month) - value1) di FROM TABLENAME)
   WHERE di <> 0
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on the [`lag`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) window aggregate function:

```
SELECT   id,
         count(CASE WHEN value > prev_value THEN 1 END) Increases,
         count(CASE WHEN value < prev_value THEN 1 END) Decreases
FROM     (SELECT id,
                 month,
                 value,
                 lag(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month) AS prev_value
          FROM   mytable)
GROUP BY id
```

If you just run the inner query, you can see how it puts the previous value next to the current value in each record.